# How to extract link from href using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am try to extract url from the href but they will give me the empty list

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    headers ={
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
    }
    r =requests.get('https://www.redfin.com/city/5357/WA/Edmonds')
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    tra=soup.find_all('div',class_='bottomV2')
    for links in tra:
        for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
            comp=link['href']
            print(comp)
```

Comment: Take a look into your soup - "Oops!  It looks like our usage analysis algorithms think that you
    might be a robot.  Accessing the redfin.com in an automated fashion is a
    violation of the <a class="link" href="/docs/tos.html">Redfin's terms of use.</a>"

Comment: Now what can I  do to solve these problem kindly guide us

Comment: You can go to the page (as human), save it as an HTML file and read it into `soup` from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the desired output:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers ={
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
    }
r =requests.get('https://www.redfin.com/city/5357/WA/Edmonds',headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tra=soup.find_all('div',class_='bottomV2')
for links in tra:
    link=links.find('a',href=True)
    comp=link['href']
    abs_url = f'https://www.redfin.com{comp}'
    print(abs_url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/31-Pine-St-98020/unit-301/home/21500390
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Lynnwood/18785-76th-Ave-W-98036/home/175276722      
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/8104-238th-St-SW-98026/unit-C/home/2820302  
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/6021-145th-St-SW-98026/home/2771575
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/21001-88th-Pl-W-98026/home/2652799
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/920-Dayton-St-98020/home/2683005
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/19730-86th-Pl-W-98026/home/2742187
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/1227-8th-Ave-S-98020/home/2757086
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/7505-181st-Pl-SW-98026/home/2703399
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/1015-Maple-St-98020/home/2682773
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/7300-176th-St-SW-98026/home/2718839
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/23706-84th-Ave-W-98026/home/2698405
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/7217-Meadowdale-Beach-Rd-98026/home/17505861https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/15419-58th-Pl-W-98026/home/176811540        
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/15423-58th-Pl-W-98026/home/176811536        
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/840-Daley-St-98020/home/2683310
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/6106-136th-Pl-SW-98026/home/2822544
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Shoreline/115-NW-205th-St-98177/unit-115/home/176726040
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Lynnwood/19814-76th-Ave-W-98036/home/2552538        
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/15407-58th-Pl-W-98026/home/176686464        
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Lynnwood/18751-76th-Ave-W-98037/home/175276737      
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/7903-218th-St-SW-98026/home/2697000
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/907-Dayton-St-98020/home/2682997
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/17802-Talbot-Rd-98026/home/2754375
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/19126-94th-Ave-W-98020/home/175037005       
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/191-94th-Ave-W-98020/home/174864268
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/12627-Possession-Ln-98026/home/103506228    
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/827-Fir-St-98020/home/2763817
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/9503-Bowdoin-Way-98020/home/2666913
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Picnic-Point-North-Lynnwood/131-Puget-Sound-Blvd-98026/home/108288661
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/23726-100th-Ave-W-98020/home/146161823      
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/7223-224th-St-SW-98026/unit-J9/home/2782416 
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/0-xxx-Olympic-View-Dr-Unknown/home/175079254https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/18230-91st-Ave-W-98026/home/2545485
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/13531-67th-Ave-W-98026/home/161335515       
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/15805-72nd-Ave-W-98026/home/2718730
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/95-Main-St-98020/home/175589481
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/14920-72nd-Ave-W-98026/home/2713344
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/7317-Lake-Ballinger-Way-98026/home/2707535  
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/15604-75th-Pl-W-98026/home/112973708        
https://www.redfin.com/WA/Edmonds/Trailside-at-Meadowdale-Beach/Residence-GR-24/home/175129446
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one alternativ approach, you can use [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html).

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('YOUR PATH TO CHROMEDRIVER')
driver.get('https://www.redfin.com/city/5357/WA/Edmonds')
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

tra=soup.find_all('div',class_='bottomV2')
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=link['href']
        print(comp)
```